# How many points do the graphs of the following functions have on the $x$-$y$ axis? Infinite or finite?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on this question and cannot figure it out,

$$y=-4-x$$

$$y=\frac{1}{x}-x$$

The first equation is a line, so should it not have infinite points?

The second equation has a restriction, $x \ne 0$, thus, does this mean it has finite points?

What is the answer, and why?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the $x$-$y$ axis? Do you mean the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis respectively?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  The question was worded like this.  I'm not sure if they mean how many points when x=0 and how many points when y=0, or just how many points exist in space for (x,y).

Comment: My guess is that they want an answer like the one below. The wording is a bit misleading, but I think that by $x$-$y$-axis they mean the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis as separate entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation is a straight line. Hence it will have one point on the $x$-axis (when $y=0$) and one point on the $y$-axis (when $x=0$). So, the point $(-4,0)$ is the only point of $y = -4-x$ on the $x$-axis. Similarly, $(0,-4)$ is the only point of $y = -x-4$ that is on the $y$-axis.

For $y = \dfrac{1}{x}-x$, a similar method can be applied. When $y=0$, then $x = \dfrac{1}{x}$. So $x = \pm 1$. When $x = 0$, then this is undefined. We never touch the $y$-axis.